# Entity Framework inheritance : table per concrete class (DB first)

Tags: c#, .net, inheritance, entity-framework-4

I'm new to Entity Framework, I need to implement the table per class inheritance strategy. This followed the steps explained in this tutorial

https://www.packtpub.com/books/content/entity-framework-db-first-%E2%80%93-inheritance-relationships-between-entities

But I get this error:

> employee and vendor entity are not mapped

I found this article not well detailed. Can you give me more explanations?

Thanks to everyone

Answer (score 1):

Something going wrong in the mapping of your DbContext, anyway here is a very  good example and description. Just follow the tutorial step by step and good luck!

http://weblogs.asp.net/manavi/inheritance-mapping-strategies-with-entity-framework-code-first-ctp5-part-3-table-per-concrete-type-tpc-and-choosing-strategy-guidelines

Comment: i'm in db first approach

Comment: @fatiDev Sorry & here is DB-First link: http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/gilf/2010/01/25/table-per-concrete-type-inheritance-in-entity-framework/